# Shortcut if within ng-click without else

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, if-statement, angularjs-ng-click

I tried to find an answer to my question, but nothing helped me really. What I need is a shortcut if within a ng-click without an else expression, just with an if condition and what happens if this condition is true. So normally you would write a shortcut if like this:

`ng-click="ctrl.isBoolean ? 'yes' : 'no'"` is the same as:

```
if(isBoolean) {
    alert('yes');
} else {
    alert('no');
}
```

But now I just need the if condition and the part what happened if it's true. I tried this:

```
ng-click="ctrl.isBoolean ? 'yes'"
```

I thought this could be similar to this, because this one is possible:

```
if(isBoolean) {
    alert('yes')
}
```

It didn't work. Any ideas? I hope this is possible.

Comment: Try `void()`function, `ng-click="ctrl.isBoolean ? 'yes' : void(0)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some solutions, I hope one will fit your needs:

**1)** Create this function in your controller. It will verify **bool**, and execute **func** if `true`.

```
$scope.if = function(bool, func) {
   if(bool) func();
};
```

You can use it as a shortcut in HTML: `{{if(myBool, myAction)}}`

I've created a **[demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/bbyxt9sq/)** for this solution.

---

**2)** `ng-click="ctrl.isBoolean && yourAction()"`

It will execute `yourAction()` if your condition is satisfied.

---

**3)** `ng-click="ctrl.isBoolean ? yourAction() : null"`

It uses the ternary operator, and the synthax is clear: if `isBoolean == true`, you will execute `yourAction()`, else nothing.

---

**4)** `ng-click="{{check(ctrl.isBoolean)}}"` and in your controller:

```
$scope.check = function(toCheck) {
    if(toCheck) yourAction();
}
```

In my opinion, this is the *"Angularest" way*, but you won't have a shortcut as you wanted...

Answer (score 0):

```
ng-click=" ctrl.isBoolean &&  showAlert('yes')"
```

You can try like this

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('demoApp',[
 
 
])

  
// Home controller
.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope',function($scope) {

 

$scope.ctrl = {
  isBoolean : true
}

$scope.showAlert = function(msg){
alert(msg);
};


}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="demoApp"  ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<button type="button" ng-click=" ctrl.isBoolean &&  showAlert('yes')">
Click here
</button>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should make 2 elements , use `ng-show`

```
 <button ng-show="ctrl.isBoolean === 'yes'" ng-click="ctrl.Boolean('yes')>Boolean</button>
 <button ng-show="ctrl.isBoolean === 'no'" ng-click="ctrl.Boolean('no')>Boolean</button>
```

then on your controller:

```
$scope.Boolean = function(val) {
   $scope.isBoolean = val;
   $scope.isBoolean === 'yes' ? alert('yes') : alert('no');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what I need is a way how to make a shortcut if without an else expression or the information if this is possible or not... Take care to the question, I know similar workarounds but my question is clear enough...